# PayPal Invoicing Multiple Peer to Peer Capabilities

Tags: paypal, invoice

I'm a software developer working on a homeschool registration website.  I have a use case I'm not sure PayPal Invoicing can handle.

The scenario:  I have Families and Teachers.  Families select a number of classes and checkout.  At time of checkout, I want to generate (what I think of as) an invoice to the Family.  I want the invoice to request the family to pay the teacher(s) for the selected classes.  I do not want to collect payments myself and redistribute payment to teachers - this raises too many issues about contractors/employees.  Payments need to take place peer to peer, Family to Teacher(s).

When payments have been made, I would like a notification for each item on the invoice (a teacher being paid) at which point, I can lock in the enrollment of that family in the class, as it has been paid.

So, is this something PayPal Invoicing can do?  I want to emphasize that I want the family to receive a single request to pay multiple teachers, not multiple requests to pay a single teacher.  And, all families and teachers are assumed to have PayPal accounts.

Also, I saw that pricing is 2.9% + $0.30.  Does the recipient of the invoice (the family) pay this, or does the organization issuing the invoice (the homeschool) pay this?  The homeschool is a non profit.  Can this be done without fees?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The transaction mode on your platform is a peer-to-peer / marketplace payment flow, so you may want to implement PayPal Adaptive Payments instead of Invoicing service.

As the platform/APP owner (API caller), you would easily manage the transactions with these implementations:

1. Adaptive - Parallel payments to fullfill the payment request (one to many) from family to teachers
2. IPN (Instant Payment Notification) to handle the transaction call-backs, your back-office program will be able to lock in the enrollment of that family in the class, based on the payment call-backs.
3. Adaptive Payments will support flexible fees payer, so that you would be able to set either the family or the teachers to bear the cost

See the overview & technical instructions at the [PayPal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) as an intro, and obtain the SDK per your programming language at [HERE](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/)

Comment: This looks very promising.  It looks like there is a limit of 6 parallel payments, I would need as many as 20 to handle the number of people that need to be paid at a given time.  I suppose I can issue multiple requests.

Comment: Exactly, you would consider "split the order" and leverage that with multiple requests

Answer (score 0):

The Invoicing API isn't what you want.

What I would recommend is an [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) integration setup with [Parallel Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#idd47bb43b-3cdc-420e-b01e-5f2fff24a33f).  You won't have to mess with Permissions if you do it that way, and the individual amounts can go directly to each teacher (receiver) on the transaction.

If you happen to be working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the Express Checkout Calls very simple for you.

Comment: This looks also promising.  I wonder why this looks so similar to Adaptive Payments?  Is it a simplified version of such?  Also, this has a limit of 10 payees, and I would need as many as 20 for my purposes, and I would frequently go beyond 10.

Comment: Express Checkout is the original set of APIs for general PayPal payment integration.  Over the years it has improved and they added the ability to handle parallel payments with it.  Adaptive Payments was introduced later and it provides for both parallel or chained payments.  In your case parallel works well and Express Checkout is much nicer than Adaptive overall, so that's what I would recommend.  Either way, though, you'll be limited to 10.  Nothing you can do about that except for split it up into multiple calls.  In that case, though, you would need Adaptive with Preapproval profiles.